# Почему после установки apk приложение не запускается?

Tags: android, apk

Почему после установки apk приложение не запускается? Если нажать на кнопку run, то android studio без проблем установит приложение и оно работает, но если попробовать установить через сгенерированный apk, то после установки приложение на запускается, сразу вылетает.

Comment: В форточку что ли вылетает? У ошибки есть имя и стектрейс , но мы их здесь не видим. Если запускается дебаг и падает релиз - значит конфигурация разная - см. build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

Гадаю ! ваша проблема скорее всего в манифесте, вероятно вы указали неправильно либо старт окно, либо допустили ошибку при создании кода, если ваше приложение берет данные из какой то библиотеки на которую у вас нет разрешение в манифесте, то у вас будет ошибка, если вы подключите телефон к ПК через порт и запустите Android Studio то в панель логов будет  указываться ошибка которая происходит в момент запуска приложения.

Comment: Все, что выбрасывается это Application terminated.

Comment: @testermatrix возможно вы смотрите не в той панели.